# Flux architecture in php from Backend Perspective

Tags: php, design-patterns, backend, flux

**Strictly from backend perspective, How do I implement Flux Architecture?** To be clear, MVC design pattern is actually clear on how the files should be arranged, frameworks have their own implementation but still are clear on how project is to be arranged, and organized. What should I structure my project code  according to Flux Architecture? Also *Are there any open source framework for Flux architecture, like codeignighter is for MVC?*

Of all the articles I have read and tutorials I have seen on Facebook's Flux architecture, They all are demonstrated using Nodejs Backend and front-end is commonly reactJS ( I have read one with angularJS too ). But they all are focused on Front-End perspective.

I was never a fan of MVC, and ever since I discovered Micro-frameworks, I have used my own version of Modal-View design pattern (surprisingly similar to a stripped down Flux pattern). But I have always been hazy on how I should structure it.

Facebook's post on Flux pattern explains a lot about speed and security. But all the tutorials focus only on ReactJS.  Tutorials from Pluralsight, egghead and everything else I have come across past year, uses a NodeJS backend. 99% of them don't really demonstrate flux architecture, but shows working with ReactJS. *So After almost year long of searching, I am still unclear on what flux exactly is.*

Comment: **Downvoters at-least have a curtsy  of explaining why you downvoted.** What you didn't like can be changed, What you didn't understand can be explained. Anonymous downvoting will help no one. You are actually obstructing someone's learning.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it's probably because the question is too broad

Comment: I Edited the question and Restructured my question to make it bit more clear on what I want to understand. Thanks for the tip @Rasclatt,

Comment: Downvoters should comment. The question shows a very bad understanding of react, flux, probably mvc and front-end/back-end separation but it's not  a reason to downvote. At least comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific backend architecture, flux pattern is for frontend. Also it's build with specific react elements that's why you won't find other implementation.
You can copy the principle in order to produce the same scheme in another framework

[image: https://facebook.github.io/flux/img/flux-simple-f8-diagram-explained-1300w.png]

Comment: I am not so sure this.  FB specifically said MVC pattern fails for very large project, delaying the content delivery to client. so they moved the from Facebook Code from MVC to Flux. I think they were talking about Backend.

Comment: So according to you, All i need in backend, a modal which forwards the data to client, and react element in client will show it on the page.  I always thought "DIspatcher" and "Action" are server components.  Let me try your way.

Comment: not at all dispatcher is a simple frontend singleton and Action is a file that gather the front interaction and eventually the calls to the server. React and flux are all about front-end. I would say flux is a kind of MV* pattern

Comment: In my current working, There are get routers which loads the first pages. And then I use lots of $.ajax requests to post routers, which returns complete html code that I update on the page.  So I just need to switch from $.ajax to ReactJS, in Front-End, adjust what Backend returns.  I need not apply any major restructuring of Backend Application? I am getting on right track?

Comment: Also please clear this for me. You said `actions` call to the server. I am sure some of the tutorials told that dispatchers are analogues to ajax requests in traditional JS working. So I was under assumption that my ajax code are dispatchers, and Actions are the even handling code which watches the clicks and scroll events etc.

Comment: You are misunderstanding dispatcher. No tutorial is saying it makes any call. Also there is only one dispatcher. Dispatcher is a simple singleton making communication between actions and stores. You don't need to update your backend. Also saying " I just need to switch from $.ajax to ReactJS, in Front-End" does not make any sense. You'll make your ajax call in actions, and then actions will use the dispatcher to populate the stores, then views are to stores and updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no flux pattern for PHP. There is an libevent based php server core called React.php though.

You ask the wrong question thinking in mvc and patterns and that's why I'll try to explain a different view and even why they use nodejs examples. So first nodejs is not mvc, not a framework too, but a simple server process to call worker threads- the apache server/nginx in typical php or also called "dispatcher". Action handlers are simple classes with a method to run on events or functions(imagine the raw php way in calling scripts for templates or code using the web server as router and not having a router in a php framework). So this is something like going back to raw payternless php with some differences:

- action handlers are sleeping workers. They don't execute without an event and can be thousands. If they were up we could have lets say 10 before the server dies.
- action handles have very little and specialized code using as low resources as possible and running in 0.000x seconds if possible. Like the simple

Echo "hello world";

Instead of framework. You need to take lets say 8mb per thread instead of 300mb to run symfony 2.

- you have a php app running and acting as a replacement for apache. Connections are with websockets in synchronous non blocking mode(libevent way)

So nodejs is built as an extendable dispatcher and js is still not bloated with design patterns and frameworks. That's why they use it for examples- it breaks the "this is not proper as is not design pattern and framework code" bareer.

For flux you need to go back to the raw php way of thinking, believing in the Rasmus Lerdorf words "They all suck!" On a question what he things about frameworks and then extending the idea with multithreaded raw php very simple and resource saving code.

That's why facebook started the first flux demo with "MVC is a bad paradigma for large scale projects and can't be supported or extended. We created an architecture to break it.". Design patterns are deeply based on mvc. Flux is back to functional like code in a simple oop representation for readability. But less classes and inheritances and simple code without models/entities for every table record are a must.

So there is a Symphony react based bundle that makes an app from symfony project. But you use sumfony to boot the dispatcher and after that you should be crazy to use doctrine, twig and so on. Apache + symfony and http requests will do better as scripts die and you don't need to keep 100mb for each of 5000 threads, but 300mb x 5 at a time. If you use flux, you forget mvc. Lets say it again FLUX IS A WAY TO FORGET ABOUT MVC, PATTERNS AND FRAMEWORKS and start thinking on the business problem and needs and write clear and simple code again.

Comment: Dbf, I am not a native english speaker and as a programmer am chaotic in explanations. Thanks for the corrections.